# Autopost back timing out - Only in opera

Tags: c#, asp.net, opera, autopostback

I don't really know where to start with this one and posting code is hard because there are a few routines that are involved. Basically, I generate a bunch of radio buttons at runtime and add them to a placeholder on my form with autopostback="true". The post back then looks up some data when the radio button is clicked.

This is working fine in Moz, IE, Chrome and Safari but for some reason it just keeps timing out in Opera (the page loading icon will just keep spinning until I get an error saying `Request timed out.` Sometimes I will get an error emailed through as `Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.` but my viewstate isn't massive (about 3k chars) so I am assuming this is a red herring (so to speak).

1. I have checked the postback urls in all browsers and they all match.
2. I have tried manually setting the form `action="myUrl"` using JS to see if this would help but to no avail.
3. I have removed the code from the update panel so it is doing a bog standard post back and the problem still occurs.

I don't really know where to go from here so am asking for some guidance.

Comment: did you solve your issue? Do you have a link online with the code?

Comment: +1 - a link would be very helpful to understand this problem.